# Regular text between nested elements using LXML / Etree

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I'm using lxml's etree to work my way through an xml file. I'm trying to access the **TARGET TEXT** within the text tag below but can't seem to get at it.

Code I'm using and example snippet is as follows

```
<page number="1" position="absolute" top="0" left="0" height="1188" width="918">
    <text top="260" left="614" width="139" height="22" font="3">No problem with this text</text>
    <text top="294" left="76" width="439" height="21" font="6">
       <b>Here is some text ​</b> **TARGET TEXT**
       ​<i>More text here </i>
    </text>
```

```
for page in root.findall('page'):
    text = []
    for child in page.iter():
        if (child.text is not None) and 
           (child.tag in ['text','b','i','a']) and 
           (len(child.text.strip())>0):

                if child.tag in ['b','i','a']:
                    parent = child.getparent()
                    if parent.tag != 'text':
                        parent = parent.getparent()
                    attributes = parent.attrib

                elif child.tag == 'text':
                    attributes = child.attrib

            sent = child.text.strip()
            attributes.update({'text': sent})
            attributes = {key: value for (key, value) in attributes.items()}
            text.append(attributes)
```

I'm currently extracting the following text:
*No problem with this text*, *Here is some text*, *More text here*

I'm able to access the text in the regular text tag and if there's nested b or i tags, but not when there is text sandwiched between nested tags as in the case above.

**SOLVED**

Updated with solution thanks to comments below indicating what I need is the tail of the b tag.

Slightly modified above so it now reads:

```
for page in root.findall('page'):
    text = []
    for child in page.iter():
        if (child.text is not None) and 
           (child.tag in ['text','b','i','a']) and 
           (len(child.text.strip())>0):

                if child.tag in ['b','i','a']:
                    if child.tail:
                        child.text = child.text+child.tail
                    parent = child.getparent()
                    if parent.tag != 'text':
                        parent = parent.getparent()
                    attributes = parent.attrib
```

Comment: `**TARGET TEXT**` is actually the .tail of `b`.

Comment: Thanks @DanielHaley and stovfl - I've never come across tail before but that's sorted it. I'll update the question with the solution in case it's helpful to someone else